# Как правильно реализовать перехват sms в android?

Tags: android, broadcast-receiver, sms

У меня в приложение надо было реализовать чтение четырехзначного `sms` кода и вставка в `EditText`.
Я вроде реализовал, все работает, с соответствующими разрешениями (read send sms permission).
Во время публикации `google` выдал предупреждение, и надо было заполнить заявку, что я и сделал.
Но я получил отказ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно реализовать чтение sms?
И как правильно заполнить заявку в моем случае?

Comment: Так всё просто, ты написал что у тебя приложение СМС мессенджер, а они отклонили, потому что это не так. Ты написал что чтение СМС это смысл твоего приложения, но это ведь не так, тут всё так и написано

Comment: Наверное сейчас вот так это правильно делать: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/automatic-sms-verification-with-sms-user-consent-da8c16135e25